# Check Conditions in SQL Queries not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL with the following schema

```
SessionKey | FieldName         | FieldValue  
-----------+-------------------+------------
     1     | resroom_Adults    |      2  
     1     | resroom_Children  |      0  
     2     | resroom_Adults    |      4   
     2     | resroom_Children  |      0  
     3     | resroom_Adults    |      3  
     3     | resroom_Children  |      2
```

I am trying to evaluate 2 scenario in a query where

1. the fieldname = 'res_adult' and fieldvalue>3
2. the fieldname = 'res_adult' and fieldvalue>=2 and the fieldname='res_child' and fieldvalue>2

If any of the conditions is satisfied, my code should return 1 else 0.

My Query written is

```
 IF Exists    
       (select * 
        from ReservationContractRulesObjectDefinitions 
        where sessionkey=@sessionkey 
        and ((FieldName = 'resroom_Adults' and fieldvalue > 3) 
              OR ((FieldName = 'resroom_Adults' and fieldvalue >=2) 
                   AND (FieldName = 'resroom_Children' and fieldvalue>2)
                  )
            )
       ) 
 begin select 1 End Else begin Select 0 End
```

In the above query only the first condition is checked. 
However, the 2nd condition is never checked. 
Could somebody help me please.

Comment: The 2nd condition will only run if adults is equal to 2. Is this intended? Also, the fieldnames don't match up from the schema to your sql code.

Comment: do you want `{0,1}` for each SessionKey? or for the whole table?

Comment: How can `fieldname` be both `'res_adult'` and `'res_child'` on the same row?

Comment: Hi pteronewone, yes the 2nd condition will only run if adults <=2. My mistake on the fieldnames. the ones in the query are actual values

Comment: Hi Juan, I want 0,1 for each sessionkey

Comment: checking your data, no session have `fieldname='res_child' and fieldvalue > 2` so only first condition can be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select (case when max(case when FieldName = 'resroom_Adults' and fieldvalue > 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 1
             when max(case when FieldName = 'resroom_Adults' and fieldvalue >= 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                  max(case when FieldName = 'resroom_Children' and fieldvalue > 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 1 
             else 0
        end)
from ReservationContractRulesObjectDefinitions 
where sessionkey = @sessionkey ;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, This works for the first condition. However, when the 2nd condition resroom_adults=2 and resroom_Children=2 then the condition returns 1. This should return 0.